# Azure pipeline: Container port mapping not working inside deployment job

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I had a pipeline that started a container server, then tested it using curl:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- checkout: self

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Login to docker registry
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'azure-registry-1'
    command: 'login'

- bash: |
    docker run -d --name test-server \
      -p 127.0.0.1:9000:9000/tcp \
      my.azurecr.io/test-server-ubuntu:latest
    
    sleep 5
    curl http://localhost:9000/
```

Everything worked just fine.

After that I tried to use my custom image base on Ubuntu (with additional packages installed). Since I cannot use

```
vmImage: my.azurecr.io/ubuntu-with-scripting    # not working
```

I had to rewrite my pipeline like this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  containers:
  - container: builder
    endpoint: azure-registry-1
    image: my.azurecr.io/ubuntu-with-scripting

jobs:
  - deployment: Release
    environment: debug
    container: builder
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Login to docker registry
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: 'azure-registry-1'
              command: 'login'

          - bash: |
              docker run -d --name test-server \
                -p 127.0.0.1:9000:9000/tcp \
                my.azurecr.io/test-server-ubuntu:latest
              
              sleep 5
              curl http://localhost:9000/
```

The problem is that port mapping seems to stop working:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refused
```

While this works fine:

```
docker exec test-server curl http://localhost:9000/
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is it required to host your container app **inside another container**? Based on the phrased findings, we could see the connection worked when the app was hosted in **agent environment** and didn't work if the app was hosted in your **custom container environment**. To help narrow down the issue, would you try to reproduce the issue without using pipeline? You may startup your `Builder` container first and inside `Builder` container startup your `test-server` and see if the curl command still incurs the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops),

> When you specify a container in your pipeline, the agent will first fetch and start the container. Then, each step of the job will run inside the container. You **can't** have nested containers. Containers **aren't supported** when an agent is already running **inside a container**.
>
> If you need fine-grained control at the individual step level, [step targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops#step-target) allow you to choose container or host for each step.

Per you first YAML pipeline, since you haven't defined or use any `container` environment, the pipeline agent job landed on the `ubuntu-latest` **agent environment** and then all the tasks including `docker` commands were executed in the **agent environment** to login ACR and startup a container based on your ACR image; the `curl` command worked to connect the container app hosted on the **agent machine** at port `9000`.

However, you second pipeline was configured to run the deployment job `Release` in a **container environment** `container: builder`, so as soon as an `ubuntu-latest` agent was assigned for this pipeline, a `Builder` container was started based on your image `my.azurecr.io/ubuntu-with-scripting` and then **inside** the `Builder` container, your pipeline created the `test-server` container.

Comment: I have been sure that nested containers are not allowed by YAML syntax, not generally. Then I have to rewrite my pipeline without prepared image, and install packages on the fly,